# How to run kibana 4.1.3 on Mac OS?

Tags: kibana

I downloaded the code of kibana 4.1.3 in GitHub.

I tried to run it, but I don't know how?

Here is the code I used,

```
sudo npm install
sudo bower install -allow-root
grunt
```

Comment: What do bower and grunt have to do with anything? You've done nothing related to Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking at here.

I had a look here,

https://github.com/elastic/kibana

and it says this,

```
Download: http://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana
Extract the files
Run bin/kibana on unix, or bin\kibana.bat on Windows.
Visit http://localhost:5601
```

When I downloaded something from here,

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/kibana-4-1-3

The readme.txt file inside says this,

```
Installation
============
Download: http://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana
Run bin/kibana on unix, or bin\kibana.bat on Windows.
Visit http://localhost:5601
```

Which is pretty much the same. In the bin folder there is a script, kibana, and I think that is what it is telling you to run.

Hopefully that helps, but I have no specific knowledge of what you are doing here. Please expand your question if you need further help.